# dict of dicts python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a python dictionary consisting of other dictionaries like so (example):

```
{2: {4: {5: {6: {7: None}}}, 7: None}, 7: None}
```

I would like to extract the keys so that I end up with:

```
[2,4,5,6,7,None]
[2,7,None]
[7,None]
```

I have tried to solve this problem with a recursive function, however with no luck...

```
def f(d):
    paths = []
    try:
        for key in f.keys():
            path.append(f(d[key]))
    pass:
        pass
```

Is there a way to do this and how?

Comment: I don't understand how you get your expected output. Could you please explain?

Comment: Recursion doesn't help if you're just throwing away the intermediate result (i.e. `paths`) in the sub-calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to do the trick:

```
def f(d):
    paths = []
    for key, value in d.items():
        if value is None:
            paths.append([key, value])
        else:
            internal_lists = f(value)
            for l in internal_lists:
                paths.append([key] + l)
    return paths
```

1) Your try: loop is badly written: the syntax is

```
try:
    xxx
except:
    xxx
```

And do you expect a failure here? Why the try?

2) Your loop can't be right neither:

```
for key in f.keys():
```

f is a function, it does not have keys. d does.

3) When dealing with a key, you need to keep it somewhere in the output, and you don't for the moment

Comment: Thank you! works great. You are right in point 1), 2) and 3), thanks for the comments!

Comment: It would look much nicer as a generator: https://gist.github.com/eallik/6752160 :)  **UPDATE:** in Python 3, `yield from` makes it even nicer.

Comment: Thanks @ErikAllik,very clean, I will look in to that (I am using 2.7 btw.)